# Executing Monix Task in parallel

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, monix

What is best way to run multiple Monix task in parallel and then get one result? 
I have the following tasks and want to get a ResultClass.

```
import monix.eval.Task

val a: Task[A]
val b: Task[B]
val c: Task[C]

case class ResultClass(a:A, b:B, c:C)
```

[The official documentation](https://monix.io/docs/3x/tutorials/parallelism.html) only has some way to do parallel execution for same type of Tasks. 
Is there good way to execute in parallel for different type of Tasks? 
Thanks.

Comment: Try to use applicative functor typeclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monix `Task` has methods like `parMap2`, `parMap3`, `parMap4` up until 6. You could use it like this:

```
case class ResultClass(a:Int, b:String, c:Boolean)

val a: Task[Int] = Task.pure(1)
val b: Task[String] = Task.pure("Test")
val c: Task[Boolean] = Task.pure(true)

val r: Task[ResultClass] = Task.parMap3(a,b,c)(ResultClass.apply)
```